# The api with CreateMailslot function in C++ DLL failed to be called by UWP

Tags: winapi, uwp, windows-10-iot-core

C++ DLL  “DllImport” to UWP App.
UWP called this API.
The API in DLL:

```
    int CreateSingletonMutex(HANDLE *phSingletonMutex)
    {
        Singleton_mutex_t *pSingletonMutex;

        do{
            pSingletonMutex = (Singleton_mutex_t*)mem_malloc(sizeof(Singleton_mutex_t), DEFAULT_ALIGN_SIZE);
            if (pSingletonMutex == NULL)
            {
                break;
            }

            memset(pSingletonMutex, 0x0, sizeof(Singleton_mutex_t));

            LPTSTR SlotNameThis = TEXT("\\\\.\\mailslot\\mailslot_ct_maincore");
            pSingletonMutex->critSec = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
            SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR sd;
            InitializeSecurityDescriptor(&sd, SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR_REVISION);
            SetSecurityDescriptorDacl(&sd, true, NULL, false);

            SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa;
            sa.lpSecurityDescriptor=&sd;
            sa.bInheritHandle=false;
            pSingletonMutex->critSec = CreateMailslot(SlotNameThis, 0, 100, &sa);

            if (pSingletonMutex->critSec == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
            {
                int ret = GetLastError();
                mem_free(pSingletonMutex, DEFAULT_ALIGN_SIZE);
                pSingletonMutex = NULL;
            }

        } while (0);

        *phSingletonMutex = pSingletonMutex;

        return 0;
    }
```

Failed to called this api,GetLastError = 5,means "Access Denied".
I deployed this uwp app in Win10 IoTCore.

Comment: The documentation could hardly be clearer .....

Comment: The error description is inconclusive. [System error code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/debug/system-error-codes--0-499-) 4 translates to `ERROR_TOO_MANY_OPEN_FILES`. `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` is error code 5. Which one do you get?

Answer (score 1):

The [CreateMailslot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-createmailslotw) API is not available when targeting the Universal Windows Platform. The [Requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-createmailslotw#requirements) section documents this:

> - Minimum supported client: Windows 2000 Professional [**desktop apps only**]
> - Minimum supported server: Windows 2000 Server [**desktop apps only**]

You will have to find a different way to implement [Interprocess Communications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/ipc/interprocess-communications) that is available in the Universal Windows Platform (e.g. [Pipes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/ipc/pipes)).